# Sort HashMap that maps to ArrayList based on ArrayList size

Tags: sorting, arraylist, hashmap, dimension

I have a `HashMap` mapping a `Dimension` (the `key`) to an `ArrayList` of `Integers` (the `value`). How can I sort this `HashMap` based on the size of the `ArrayList` of `Integers`?

```
HashMap<Dimension,ArrayList<Integer>> map = new HashMap<Dimension,ArrayList<Integer>>();

//code to sort:
```

Comment: This is a HashMap; By design, this structure is unsorted. Do you want to get a sorted array of the ArrayList based on their size ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing you need to create a sortedMap out of this HashMap based on the size of the values.
Since HashMap cannot maintain ordering, I'm using LinkedHashMap and using **Java 8 (Streams)**.

**For Ascending order :**

```
Map<String, List<Integer>> collect = map.entrySet().stream()
                    .sorted((entry1, entry2) -> Integer.compare(entry1.getValue().size(), entry2.getValue().size()))
                    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Entry::getKey, Entry::getValue, (a,b) -> a, LinkedHashMap::new));
```

**For Descending Order :**

```
Map<String, List<Integer>> collect = map.entrySet().stream()
                    .sorted((entry1, entry2) -> Integer.compare(entry2.getValue().size(), entry1.getValue().size()))
                    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Entry::getKey, Entry::getValue, (a,b) -> a, LinkedHashMap::new));
```